# Identify websites with fb:app_id in the meta tags

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I'd like to crawl many websites, check if they've got a fb:app_id in the meta tags and store these website urls in a file.

Do you know any tool, software or service I could use for this approach?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Olli

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php take a look at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/. The usage is very similar to jQuery.